# Problema al crear consulta desde Java

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

Si, mira lo tengo de la siguiente manera :

```
public void borrarPersona(String dni) {
        Connection c = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        //Usando consultas preparadas, más seguras y más rápidas
        String insertSQL = "DELETE "
                + "FROM personas"
                + "WHERE dni LIKE ?";

        try {
            c = iniciarConnection();
            preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) iniciarConnection().prepareStatement(insertSQL);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, dni);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Registro con dni:"+dni+" ha sido borrado");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Nunca llega a salir el System.out.println, tambien lo he comprobado en la base de datos pero tampoco sale

Comment: ¿Para qué abres una pregunta nueva cuando ya has preguntado por lo mismo en otra?

Comment: pense que la gente ya habia concluido mi anterior pregunta con solo responderme la de insercion y no se habian dado cuenta de que tambien estaba la parte de eliminar

Comment: Aplica para el borrado lo mismo que para la inserción, no esperes que te den todo hecho.

Comment: eso fue lo primero que intente, pero desgraciadamente es mi primera prubea conectandome, necesito saber un preparedStatement.'algo que me devuelva de la tabla para igualarlo al dni que pongo por parametro'. 

Ese es mi problema, lo siento por no nacer sabiendo

Comment: No es cuestión de saber, sino de intentarlo.

Comment: No debes modificar el cuerpo de tu pregunta, si necesitas aclarar algo debes dejar la pregunta original, y agregar lo que te piden, si no la pregunta queda invalida con las respuestas dadas y no se entiende nada. Gracias.

Comment: lo siento, soy nuevo y no habia caido en eso, no pasara de nuevo. Gracias a todos

Comment: Los métodos para `INSERT` y para `DELETE` funcionan **igual** con consultas preparadas, lo único que cambia es la consulta. Fíjate bien en tu consulta: 1º. Hay un error de sintaxis aquí: **`+ "FROM personas"+ "WHERE dni LIKE ?";`**, si observas, **no hay espacio entre `personas` y `WHERE`**, lo cual resultará en una cadena así: **`FROM personasWHERE dni LIKE...`** 2º. No usaría `LIKE` con la columna DNI... muy peligroso, siendo que el DNI tiene valor único buscaría por dni completo, o sea: `WHERE dni = ?` Un `dni LIKE A` podría borrarte todos los registros cuyos dni tengan la letra A.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo agregas la siguiente linea: preparedStatement.setString(1,dni);
antes de executeUpdate()

```
public void borrarPersona(String dni) {
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    //Usando consultas preparadas, más seguras y más rápidas
    String insertSQL = "DELETE "
            + "FROM personas"
            + "WHERE dni = ?";       

    try {
        c = iniciarConnection();
        preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) iniciarConnection().prepareStatement(insertSQL);

        preparedStatement.setString(1,dni);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: eso no me funciona, me sigue apareciendo el registro, gracias igualmente por tu aporte

Comment: Ya intentaste cambiando tu consulta de la siguiente manera:
DELETE FROM personas WHERE dni LIKE ?

Comment: Si, mira lo tengo de la siguiente manera :

Comment: Si esta igual tu código al que estas mostrando creo que te hace falta un espacio entre personas y WHERE, si imprimes el string saldría así:

DELETE FROM personasWHERE dni = ?

y debe de ser:
DELETE FROM personas WHERE dni = ?

Comment: Eso era, un maldito espacio, gracias por tu interes y resolverme esa duda, muchisimas gracias :)